# Why text has underline with yellow color with big font size?

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, underline, yellow

Screenshot of the code and it's result:

[image]

Hi, I have `StatelessWidget` which has `Container` returning in its build method and the `Text` widget as a child widget. But it's look and feel is not as expected. Why is the `yellow` underline and how can I remove it?

I tried replacing the `Container` with `Stack`, `Column` and `Row` nothing change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of you havent wrap your `Text` widget with a material widget. You can wrap with a `Scaffold` or with `Material` widget with color property as you want.

Example:

```
Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Here is the text")))
```

or:

```
Material(color: Colors.white, child: Center(child: Text("Here is the text")))
```

Comment: The application root widget is set to scaffold in material app, one area of the ui shows yellow lines. Should they be wrapped, directly - even though the application root is scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Every screen should have a scaffold widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
             body:Container(
                  child:Text("your text"),
           ),
        );
```